# AWS: error while creating AMI from a debian 10 iso - Unsupported kernel version

Tags: import, amazon-ami, debian-buster

We have a custom Debian10 (buster) ISO and want to create an AMI using this iso.

We followed the steps from AWS documentation [Importing a VM as an image using VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-vm-image) but getting the below error :

```
ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64
```

We tried the same process with the stock Debian10 iso too and got the same error.

**Steps followed:**

1. Export image from VMWare
2. Upload the image to S3
3. Import the VM using the below command

   `aws ec2 import-image --description "My server VM" --disk-containers "file://containers.json"`

**containers.json**

```
[
{
   "Description": "Debian 10",
   "Format": "ova",
   "UserBucket": {
   "S3Bucket": "iso-to-ami",
   "S3Key": "debian-10.ova"
}
]
```

**Check upload status**

```
aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids import-ami-xxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Error message**

```
{
"ImportImageTasks": [
{
   "Description": "Debian-10-custom latest OVA",
   "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxxxxxxxx",
   "LicenseType": "BYOL",
   "SnapshotDetails": [
{
   "DeviceName": "/dev/sdf",
   "DiskImageSize": 1271036416.0,
   "Format": "VMDK",
   "Status": "completed",
   "UserBucket": {
      "S3Bucket": "iso-to-ami",
      "S3Key": "debian-10.ova"
   }
}
],
   "Status": "deleted",
   "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We checked with the AWS tech team regarding this issue and got the input that AWS supports only Debian 6 to 8, so Debian 10 is not supported.

Our main goal was to use a stripped down version of Debian 10 in EC2.

Alternatives suggested by the tech team for this approach :

- Option 1 : Use [CloudEndure](https://www.cloudendure.com/) an [AWS Application Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/application-migration-service/) to replicate the local VM (with the stripped down version of debian) to AWS.
- Option 2 : Create an EC2 instance from Debian 10 AMI available in AWS Marketplace and strip down all the libraries except the ones we require.